# How we can override history.length and track its calls?

Tags: javascript, browser, proxy, ecmascript-6

I need to track all `history.length`, or any `navigator.****` calls in browser (into console.log for example). How can I do this?
Seems, I need to override them, but I don't know how.

Comment: html5 history api

Comment: Sorry, and what? API doesn't has any method that provide ability to track how many times we call `history.length` in our js script.

Comment: I thought you were asking how to monitor it. There is no way to know when you reference properties of an object. If it were a method you could override it, but properties are not that easy to change the getter/setter. Seems like a weird task you are performing....

Comment: I've tried to do it via Proxy, but I haven't success with it

Comment: What is your actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: For example we inject any script for metric track, library, framework etc.  in our html page. I need to track what information this script try to fetch from our browser and how many times.

Comment: getting into sensitive areas that you probably can't override for fairly obvious security reasons. Curious why you would need to do this

Comment: Root Cause: security reasons =) So, I have two main points: I need to check (and track every time) that nothing of linked stuff will not check browser info. Other reason, - sometimes we use headless browser, and we want to hide that from this analitic libs, etc.

Comment: I know that this is strange, but that's the problem. And it makes sense for me.